# Set frame subtitle size

Tags: beamer, fontsize

What is the correct way to set subtitle size? I have this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but the subtitle appears in scriptsize, not Large. I can put the `\Large` command inside the `\setbeamertemplate` argument, before `\insertframesubtitle`, and it works; but why it does not work in this way? What's wrong in my code?

Comment: It would seem like `insertframesubtitle` does not actually inherit the font definition from `framesubtitle` but rather just typesets the text.

Comment: @ach but it does inherit the the size from  `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}` so if in my example you set `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large}` the subtitle changes to Large. Is this a bug or is the intended behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour; `\insertframesubtitle` just inserts the subtitle; if you want the effect of `\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=<font switch>}` to be taken into account in your redefinition of the `frametitle` template, you need to use the font with `\usebeamerfont`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you mean my redefinition of the "frametitle" template? Or is there also a "framesubtitle" template?

Comment: @murena In your redefinition; there's no `framesubtitle` template; I made a little mistake that I've fixed in my updated answer.