# Framesubtitle in a different color than Frametitle in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, frame-title

I was wondering if it is possible to have a different colour for your `framesubtitle` than the colour your `frametitle` has?

I found out how to change the fontsize seperately here: [Set frame subtitle size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120516/set-frame-subtitle-size)

So I thought I'd try the same thing for the colour (inside a custom template) (the lines of code are not really all underneath each other, but spread out in the template files...)

```
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=yellow}%

\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}%

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{my theme}
{%
  \vskip.2cm
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[right]{frame title}%
    \insertframetitle\\\usebeamercolor{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

However the colour does not change one bit...
What am I doing wrong? Or if there is a totally different way to do this, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify which component of the `beamercolor` you want to use. So if you want to use the foreground colour, use `usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}`. For the background component, it would be `[bg]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=yellow}%

\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}%

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{my theme}
{%
    \vskip.2cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[right]{frame title}%
        \insertframetitle\\\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{blub}
        \framesubtitle{test}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Chocolate_Althea You are welcome!